# Expect doesn't recognize output on Cisco router

Tags: ssh, cisco, router, expect

I'm writing a script with `expect` to configure cisco routers automatically via `ssh`.
A part of this script is to copy an image into `flash` if it doesn't exist:

For this expect sends a `copy` and waits for `Destination filename` then sends a `return`.

```
cisco#copy tftp://10.xx.xx.3/name_of_image.bin flash:
Destination filename [name_of_image.bin]?
```

---

Now there're two options:

1. The File doesn't exist and gets copied into `flash:`
2. The File exists and the script skips this part.

---

If the file already exists it looks like this:

```
%Warning:There is a file already existing with this name
Do you want to over write? [confirm]
```

Now to my problem:
The scripts waits for `Do you want to over write? [confirm]` and then should exit since the image is already in flash.
But currently it seems like `expect` can't recognize that line and gets stuck at the confirmation. It've tried several patterns like `[confirm]`, `*[confirm]*`, `Do`, `*write*` and some more.

My code for that job looks like this at the moment:

```
        expect "*#"
        send "copy tftp://10.$ip_local.3/name_of_image.bin flash:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"

        expect {
          "Do you want to over write? [confirm]"{
           interact
           abort
        }
        expect "*#"
        send "exit\r"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things wrong:

- in a double-quoted string `[confirm]` will attempt to call the expect command "confirm" -- square brackets in expect are like backticks in the shell
- expect needs to have arguments separated by whitespace. Therefore it's critical to put a space before the opening curly brace
- your script does not expect the overwrite prompt *conditionally*. You need to use the multi-pattern form of the `expect` command, where the first one matched wins.

Try this:

```
expect {
    -exact {Do you want to over write? [confirm]} {
        send "\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*#"
}
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Notes

- I'm using "exact" matching since you have glob wildcards `?` and `[...]` that would interfere.
- I'm using expect's no-interpolation quotes (curly braces) to prevent `[confirm]` from attempting command substitution
- I expect *either* the overwrite prompt *or* the command prompt
- I use `exp_continue` to remain within this expect command if the overwrite prompt appears. That means that I can still look for the command prompt.
- the above 2 bullets are how to implement conditional matching.
- I assume you just want to hit enter at the overwrite prompt.
- after you `exit`, wait for `eof` to allow the ssh session to end normally